# How to reduce font weight in Firefox on Mac with CSS?

Tags: css, macos, firefox, fonts

Here's my problem: I'm using font-face for the menu of my website, but Firefox on Mac displays it too bold
On a PC, everything works well, the font is perfectly sized and looks like it should

Unfortunatly, on Mac, i have to had a CSS hack for Safari (which works), but I didn't find anything similiar in Firefox.

I've tried the "text-shadow hack", i tried using the font-weight property (which pretty much doesn't do anything).

And now, some code!

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'KnockoutHTF48FeatherweightRg';
    src: url('font/knockout-htf48-featherweight-webfont.eot');
    src: url('font/knockout-htf48-featherweight-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('font/knockout-htf48-featherweight-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('font/knockout-htf48-featherweight-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('font/knockout-htf48-featherweight-webfont.svg#KnockoutHTF48FeatherweightRg')     format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

For Safari:

```
body{
    ...
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

Left if FF on Mac and right is FF on PC (the good version)
[image: Screenshot]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of HTML.  Just wait til you try it on a phone!

Comment: Don't worry, I've been in the HTML word for a while... and I keep crying over IE every time ;). Luckily my customer also wants a mobile website, so I don't have to deal with that problem!

Comment: i would be careful using knockout... that font is copyright protected and is ONLY available for legal use through typography.com's cloud service...

Comment: @kristinachilds this was used a few years ago, by the agency for which i worked, I'm sure they acquired it legally. Thanks for the info tho :)

Comment: @Ebpo no worries :) it's the brand font for one of my clients and we just recently purchased it for web use so i was just lookin' out :)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

FireFox posted a resolution to this today on their bug forum. It was just finalized today so won't be in use for a while, but we should all put

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
```

in our `body` tag to reset this for all browsers. FINALLY!! man, that made my day! This should come out in the next FF release.

thread here
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=857142

Comment: It's about freaking time! Thanks for the info!

Comment: Works for FF 25 final, not for FF 24. Let's hope it doesn't get removed later unless Apple changes their mind about font antialiasing again.

Comment: Confirmed working in FF26 and FF27. Fixed our issue.

Comment: should make this the answer

Comment: This really helped with font smoothing on Firefox. Didn't know that CSS rule existed. Thanks!

Comment: This made my day!  Thank you so much.  Note that this is still an issue in 2015 on a Mac using Chrome version 44... and the above fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

you can use,

```
font-weight:normal !important;
```

for fix the visualization error on firefox Mac.

Comment: -webkit-font-smoothing option below is a better solution

Answer (score 2):

This affects firefox browser ONLY.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  .classname {
    font-weight:normal;

    /* or any other option */
  }
}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

There is trick explained http://dave-bond.com/css/font-too-bold-on-a-mac/
basically is to apply opacity: 0.99; to those texts...

Comment: I tried this trick and it actually caused child layers with a higher z-index to become partially transparent and slightly "see through" to what was beneath them. I didn't think 1% would do that but it was unacceptable for say a hover menu. So to use this successfully, you just have to make sure that you won't be floating any layers inside of the elements you apply this style to, or if so, add the appropriate exception to the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Every font supports different weights. Some can be really thing, others can't.

Mac and PC will render the same font differently. It's a core operating system thing, and basically, there's nothing you can do about it. :(

Most consistent results can be achieved using something like [Google Webfonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) or [TypeKit](http://typekit.com).

One of the thinnest fonts standard on Mac is Helvetica Neue.

Also worth noting that font-weight  supports values 100,200,...800,900.

Comment: Even thought font-weight supports values other than normal and bold, most of the time, the different values will not work. for example, 400, 500, 600 might act like normal, while 700 and up will act like bold. (If I correctly remember).
I know Mac and PC supports font differently, but as you see there is a hack for Safari, so I was wondering if there is something similar for FF

Comment: And sometimes you just have to use an image.

Comment: @DanielRHicks I was trying to avoid using images (or things like Cufon), because I already have a lot of javascript for animations and HUGE images as sliding background for the window). But I don't think I'llhave a choice...

Answer (score 0):

I've found that making a slightly "lighter" version of the icons is the best way to compensate for this. They're passable in Firefox, and ever-so-slightly lighter in all other browsers. In Illustrator, I create a 16px icon. I resize it to 1024px, and apply an offset path of -6px (these are the numbers that worked best for me). I then export that as a svg, and import it into IcoMoon to build the icon-font. I don't use -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased (or the pending -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale) unless it's a light icon over a dark background. This is the best way I've found to get icon-fonts to display (mostly) uniformly across browsers & platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Found this on CSS Tricks and this freaking works.

add this to the stylesheet:
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;