# Firefox Mac and Firefox Windows font rendering differences

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have attached the image for what I am facing right now, there is a lot of difference between firefox for windows and firefox for mac, I have checked other browsers so far, Mac Firefox, Mac Chrome, and Windows chrome are showing the same results, but the firefox on windows is having different font.

[image: Font Rendering Differences]

I also have included the text properties by inspecting element via firebug.

Any idea why firefox for windows is having different font rendering? and How I can improve it. This issue breaks the whole layout for complex forms.

Answer (score 2):

What I have heard, is that Firefox under Mac uses different font algorithms.

Try the following

```
html, body {
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Comment: so will it change the mac font to look like windows? that is not required, as chrome on mac, chrome on windows and fire fox on mac all are same only firefox for windows is different

Comment: @AamirMahmood the Mac screen-shot displayed the text to be a bit choppy. I assumed that was your issue. I see no no difference other than that. But, I'm a developer, and not a designer, so might be just me.

Comment: NP, http://i.stack.imgur.com/P4dKu.jpg check col title going in 2 lines and date overlapping next column in firefox

Comment: @AamirMahmood  You probably might add a `font:inherit;` and `font-size:inherit;` maybe a `max-width` to your COL, and table and such. I don't have the code to play with, so thats - at the top of my head - is the best I can do.

Comment: add also 'webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053389/how-to-reduce-font-weight-in-firefox-on-mac-with-css

Answer (score 0):

They are different browsers on different operating systems. Difference in font rendering is inevitable, and there's nothing much you can do about it.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to fix this, so my safe exit was using `Arial` Font. `Verdana` Font size 9 is like 10/20 and `Arial` is like 18/20 where first number is FF Windows and later number is Chrome Window